# Multi-State Markov Model

Tags: markov-process

I have 100 sovereign's credit rating for last 20 years. I am using MSM package of r to model transition probilities. I want to create transition probabilities conditioned to macro-economic conditions (as an example GDP). The msm function does not take care of continous coveriate. Can anyone help me with this? How can I generate a transition probabilities matrix conditioned to macro-economic variable?

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Wouldn't this break the Markov assumption?

Comment: No, I believe it does not. But I am saying transtion of moving into next state is dependent on the previous state.